# Creating Role for EC2 Service in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a full access role (using an AWS Managed Policy) to all EC2 instances to call AWS services via Cloudformation in YAML.

This is my code:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Ansible Role
Resources:
  AnsibleRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: 'Allow'
            Action: 'ec2:*'
            Principal:
              Service: 'ec2.awsamazon.com'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess'
      RoleName: 'EC2-FullAccess'
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid principal in policy: "SERVICE":"ec2.awsamazon.com" 
(Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error
Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: e43214f8-b6f9-11e9-9891-4dc84fd279dd)
```

I am perplexed as to why it doesn't recognize the service.  Additionally, if I change `Action: 'ec2:*'` to `Action: 'sts.AssumeRole'` I get another error.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it may not be only this, but it's `ec2.amazonaws.com` (not `awsamazon`)

Comment: this may also help https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-attach-managed-policy/

Comment: change your service to -- **Service: ec2.amazonaws.com**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your template:

1. The service identifier is malformed. It should be 'ec2.amazonaws.com'.
2. The action must be 'sts:AssumeRole'. This is the only action which is valid inside an IAM trust policy.
3. The *DeletionPolicy* is not necessary because it is the default for this resource.
4. Set the *RoleName* only if really necessary because IAM names are global on a per-account basis and you cannot execute multiple stacks when using this attribute.

For more information see the [AWS CloudFormation template examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#aws-resource-iam-role--examples).

You use the correct managed policy ARN if you want to grant your new role permission to call all kinds of ec2 actions. If you want to restrict your Ansible role further, take a look at the example policies for EC2 in the docs [1][2]. They are much more restrictive (and thus secure) than the managed full access policy *AmazonEC2FullAccess*. Maybe also the other managed policies such as *AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess* [3] are feasible?

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ExamplePolicies_EC2.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html
[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UsingIAM.html#intro-to-iam